# EditText программная фокусировка и ожидание ввода Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, recyclerview

Добрый день!

В приложении необходимо реализовать поиск по списку продуктов, список - RecyclerView, поиск решено добавить в тот же Recycler как хедер. Поиск состоит из иконки и поля EditText, на котором висит TextWatcher. Поиск локальный, поэтому выполняется только для продуктов в данной категории. Необходимо, чтобы после введения символа происходило переформирование списка продуктов (проерка на содержание последовательности символов из ET в заголовке продукта) и перестроение RecyclerView. Однако я столкнулся со следующей проблемой, если для адаптера делать notifyDataSetChanged то перерисовывается весь Recycler, в том числе и итем-поиск, и EditText теряет фокус, в результате каждый раз приходится на него кликать, чтобы ввести следующий симол или стереть следующий символ. Как можно сфокусироваться на EditText и перевести его в режим вввода текста (который бывает в результате клика по нему) программно, чтобы пользователя не касалась логика?

TextWatcher такой

```
new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if (s.length() > 0) {
                        ArrayList<Product> searchResultsList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (Product p : pivotList) {
                            if (p.title().toLowerCase().contains(s.toString().toLowerCase())) searchResultsList.add(p);
                        }
                        buferList = searchResultsList;
                    } else if (s.length() == 0) {
                        buferList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (Product p : pivotList) {
                            buferList.add(p);
                        }
                    }
                    ProductGridAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    search.requestFocusFromTouch();
                    InputMethodManager lManager = (InputMethodManager)((Activity)context).getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    lManager.showSoftInput(search, 0);
                }
            }
```

buferList - лист продуктов, на основании которого строится Recycler, pivotList - все продукты в категории

Comment: А вы пробовали не все элементы менять, а только те, кои нужно методом `notifyItemChanged(int position)`? Так, возможно, не потеряется фокус на ЕТ.

Comment: [Готовая библиотека](https://github.com/Wrdlbrnft/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo) не интересует?

Comment: Юрий, спасибо, добавил                     ProductGridAdapter.this.notifyItemRangeRemoved(1, pivotList.size() - buferList.size() + 1); работает теперь как часы)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать не все элементы менять, а только те, кои нужно, методом `notifyItemChanged(int position)` Так не потеряется фокус на ЕТ, т.к. елемент не будет изменён.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void showSoftKeyboardForEditText(EditText target) {
        target.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0, 0, 0));
        target.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 0, 0, 0));
    }

...

EditText editText;

...

editText.post(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            showSoftKeyboardForEditText(editText);
        }
    });
```

Но правильным решением было бы вынести `EditText` из хедера

Comment: Почему нужно вынести его из хедера?

Comment: @iamthevoid, чтобы он не затрагивался, когда меняются элементы списка

Comment: Необходимо, чтобы скроллилась вся разметка, значит либо скролл вью и как описали Вы, и проблемы с ресайклером, либо делать отдельный viewholder, что на мой взгляд выглядит элегантнее)